# Social Sharing Palette in iOS6

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I noticed in iOS6 that when you select a photo in your photo library, and push the the "arrow in a square button", it brings up a palette with icons that enable the user to share the photo (ie icons for mail, message, photo stream, twitter, Facebook, etc). I'm wondering, is there any library in iOS6 that has a palette like this built in? (I know separately there is `SLComposeViewController` and `MFMailComposeViewController`). If there isn't, would Apple have issue if you built a palette identical to the one they have (same icons, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `UIActivityViewController`.